Can I reference snapshot_id from ebs_block_device?
I am creating AMIs from existing EC2 instance, that has 2 ebs volumes. I am using “aws_ami_from_instance”, but then the disk snapshots do not have tags. I found a way from hashi’s github to tag ‘manually’ the root snapshot, since “root_snapshot_id” is exported from the ami resource, but what can I do about the other disk?
resource "aws_ami_from_instance" "server_ami" {
  name                = "${var.env}.v${local.new_version}.ami"
  source_instance_id  = data.aws_instance.server.id
  tags = {
    Name              = "${var.env}.v${local.new_version}.ami"
    Version           = local.new_version
  }
}

resource "aws_ec2_tag" "server_ami_tags" {
  for_each    = { for tag in var.tags : tag.tag => tag }
  resource_id = aws_ami_from_instance.server_ami.root_snapshot_id
  key         = each.value.tag
  value       = each.value.value
}

I tried referring the id from ebs_block_device block, but doesn't seem to work:
│   25:   resource_id = aws_ami_from_instance.sever_ami.ebs_block_device.snapshot_id
│ Block type "ebs_block_device" is represented by a set of objects, and set
│ elements do not have addressable keys. To find elements matching specific
│ criteria, use a "for" expression with an "if" clause.

│   25:   resource_id = aws_ami_from_instance.sever_ami.ebs_block_device[snapshot_id]
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
│ access, specifying the resource name.

│   25:   resource_id = aws_ami_from_instance.sever_ami.ebs_block_device["snapshot_id"]
│ Block type "ebs_block_device" is represented by a set of objects, and set
│ elements do not have addressable keys. To find elements matching specific
│ criteria, use a "for" expression with an "if" clause.

Am I doing it wrongly or it's just not possible?

Based on how I understood the docs, it probably isn't feasible, you can maybe try using the same data source and fetch the ebs_block_device attribute.

Hi Marko. I tried to fetch the ebs volume_size so I can use it in a filter, but I get a similar set error:
data "aws_ebs_snapshot" "trails_snapshot" {
depends_on  = [aws_ami_from_instance.server_ami]
most_recent = true
owners      = ["self"]
filter {
name   = "status"
values = ["pending"]
}
filter {
name   = "volume-size"
values = ["${data.aws_instance.server_ami.ebs_block_device.volume_size}"]
}
}
"Can't access attributes on a set of objects"

The issue is that the aws_ami_from_instance resource does not expose individual snapshot IDs for additional EBS volumes directly, except for the root snapshot root_snapshot_id. The ebs_block_device block is a set, and it doesn’t provide directly attributes like you tried to get and reference.
you can use aws_snapshot Data Source to find the Snapshots as the below example:
data "aws_ebs_snapshot" "other_snapshots" {
  for_each = toset(["${aws_ami_from_instance.server_ami.id}"])

  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "description"
    values = ["*${each.value}*"] 
  }
}

or you can use external script using local-exec using:
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filters "Name=tag:AMI,Values=<ami-id>"


Doesn't seem to work for 'future' objects as per the error:
│   on backup-running.tf line 24, in data "aws_ebs_snapshot" "trails_snapshot":
│   24:   for_each = toset(["${aws_ami_from_instance.server_ami.id}"])
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_ami_from_instance.server_ami.id is a string, known only after apply

I saw that from data.aws_ebs_snapshot we could get volume_size, so this gave me the idea to add it as a filter:
data "aws_ebs_snapshot" "trails_snapshot" {
depends_on  = [aws_ami_from_instance.server_ami]
most_recent = true
owners      = ["self"]
filter {
name   = "status"
values = ["pending"]
}
filter {
name   = "volume-size"
values = ["${data.aws_instance.server_ami.ebs_block_device.volume_size}"]
}
}
but this one also complains about the set "Can't access attributes on a set of objects"

attempting to access attributes of future values or computed sets that Terraform cannot determine until apply. Additionally, aws_ebs_snapshot cannot dynamically query snapshots during the same plan/apply cycle because snapshots are created as part of the AMI creation. For this you only can use it with depends_on, either data block or local-exec, to make sure they only run after making sure that the ebs is there:  depends_on = [aws_ami_from_instance.server_ami]

I ended up putting a variable for disk size and this way it fetches it correctly with data. The small drawback is that i have to define and manage its value if it changes. Fortunately, for my use case it rarely does.
